# Continuity of a characteristic function of a translated set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, characteristic-functions

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set. Is it true that $\chi_{E+t}(x) \rightarrow \chi_{E}(x)$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, where $E+t = \{x+t \, | \,  x \in E\}$ for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$, almost everywhere? Is there any counterexample?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you prove it for intervals?

Comment: @Spotty yes I already proved it when $E$ is an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand -- consider $E = \mathbb{Q}$. Then, since $t$ is irrational infinitely often as it $\to 0$, $\chi_{E+t}$ will be 0 on all of $E$ infinitely often, so it clearly does not converge to $\chi_E$.

Comment: When $\chi_{E + t}(x)\to\chi_E(x)$ as $t\to 0$, this means that FOR ALL such sequences $\{t_n\}_n$ that converge to zero, the sequence $\{\chi_{E + t_n}(x)\}_n$ converges to $\chi_E(x)$, so you cannot really say that $t_n$ is irrational infinitely many times (for example when $t_n = 1/n$).

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a null set. I think this cannot be a counterexample.

Comment: Ah, I re-read your question a few more times -- I wasn't sure how the "almost everywhere" fit in there. Now I see, you want a set $E$ such that for almost all $x$ in $E$, $\chi_{E+t}(x) \to \chi_E(x)$. My bad!